# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0". But after trying does not resolved.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = class Product {
    constructor(title) {
        this.title = title
    }

    saveProductData() {
        const filePath = path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename), 
        'data', 'products.json')
        fs.readFile(filePath, (err, fileContent) => {
            let products = []
            if (!err) {
                products = JSON.parse(fileContent)
            }
            products.push(this)
            fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(products), (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        })
    }

    static fetchAllProducts(cb) {
        const filePath = path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename), 
        'data', 'products.json')
        fs.readFile(filePath, (err, fileContent) => {
            if (err) {
                cb([])
            }
            cb(JSON.parse(fileContent))
        })
    }
}
```

I need to write some data on product.json file.

Comment: your `products.json` is invalid or it is not loading properly. Could you show us your json file to see it ?

Comment: look at see what you have.... `console.log(fileContent); products = JSON.parse(fileContent)`

Comment: `fetchAllProducts` is attempting to invoke `JSON.parse` *even when there is an err set*. Calling a callback does *not* immediately exit the current function. In this case it is likely fileContent is *undefined* and undefined is converted "undefined" via JSON.parse's implicit to-string conversion; and "undefined" is Invalid JSON that 'begins with "u"'.

Comment: @MasoodSadri It's `fileContent` that is `undefined`, not `JSON.parse`

Comment: @Bergi I see but how can define that?

Comment: @user2864740If JSON.parse is undefined (that I think so), so how can I define this?

Comment: Try this : cb(JSON.parse(fileContent || [])). you are fetching an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puting
 `cb(JSON.parse(fileContent))` in an `else{}` 
will solve your problem